# Wrong padding on alternating pages

Tags: geometry, layout

In the header of my `LaTeX` thesis I used the following command:

```
    \usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

But it seems to me that `LaTeX` is completely ignoring it.

[image]

Why doesn't the text fill up the whole page except for the 3cm left and 2cm right? Why do alternating pages always have the same layout?

Here is my whole header code in case that helps:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[numbers, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{helvet}

\onehalfspacing
```

Comment: Hi, if I understand correctly you always want the 2cm margin left? But since you're using `twoside` option, On even pages the margins will "change site" so the layout is consistent for two pages. maybe try to remove the option.

Comment: Hi, yeah that was it. Changed it two onside and it now looks all good!
Thank you!

Comment: Off-topic, you might want to load `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` to get correct hyphenation and spacing

Comment: There is also a missing space before the `(`

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, so that when you print your document two sided, the outer margins (which get the "left" measurement) will match, and the inner margins (which get the "right" measurement and end up next to each other) will match. If you're only going to read your document as a pdf (or only print one sided), you can use "oneside" instead of "twoside" for your report option.